# how to iterate through different key values which are generated randomly by firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

[image]
Here is the data structure which i want to traverse
as you can see users has different users which i can traverse through easily because they are userid which are generated during firebase authentication so i have access to them but now i want to traverse inside events node which has unknown key values as i create them with push also the attenance node is created with push and is supposed to have multiple value how should i traverse between them

Comment: What does `ozxF ... igg1` represent, a user id? So you want to get all `event` objects under `events` node, is this correct?

Comment: yes under users node all users are defined using their user id so the nodes are made using userid's

Comment: That's good. So you want to get all event objects under events node, is this correct?

Comment: yes i want to get every object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, there are two approaches. If you are using to add data to the database a model class named `Event`, to get the data back, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference eventsRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid).child("events");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Event event = ds.getValue(Event.class);
            Log.d(TAG, event.getName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
eventsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The second approach would be to use String class, as in the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference eventsRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid).child("events");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG, name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
eventsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

In both cases, the output in the logcat will be:

```
Yoga Camp
Blood Donation Camp
```